# What does an engineering manager do?

Tags: grammar, ambiguity

According to wikipedia [Engineering Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_management):
Engineering management is the application of the practice of management to the practice of engineering.

An **engineering manager** is a manager who manages engineers. But doesn't "engineering manager" sound ambiguous?

1. a manager who manages engineers
2. a manager who engineers something (doing the same work as engineers)

Comment: Could be either, there's no universal standard for job titles.

Comment: This in NOT a question about what an engineering manager does. This is a question about wether the phrase "engineering manager" ambiguous.

Comment: The question about the ambiguous nature of the phrase "engineering manager" is resolved only by establishing what an engineering manager actually does.

Comment: I could imagine a project having multiple managers:  an engineering manager, a financial manager, a publicity manager, and more.  If so, then the engineering manager in in charge of the engineering aspects of the project (which may or may not involve people called "engineers").

Comment: He makes life miserable for the engineers.

Comment: It is true that, so far as the meanings of its constituents words and the general rules of English language are concerned, the phrase is ambiguous. The phrase may, however, be established as a technical term, with a definite meaning, within a particular field. Whether that is the case is an inquiry that should be addressed to somebody who works in that field.

Comment: Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Thank you for the answers!